# Parámetros de SALIDA en procedimientos almacenados sql server y c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, parametros

Hola tengo una consulta como puedo presentar el contenido de un mensaje en c# messagebox que imprime una verificacion en un procedimiento almacenado sql server, logro hacer que lo llame pero el box aparece vacio y tengo que entregarlo mas tarde.
este es el codigo c#

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CampoCurso.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(CampoDescripcion.Text)
            && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbcosto.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbcupo.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbduracion.Text)
            && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbdia.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbhora.Text))
        {
            try
            {

                string query = ("EXEC CREAR_CURSO @NOMBRE,@DESCRIPCION,@C_MENSUAL,@CUPO,@DURACION,@DIA_CLASE,@HORA_CLASE,@msg");
                Conexion.Open();
                SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand(query, Conexion);

                Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE", CampoCurso.Text);
                Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESCRIPCION", CampoDescripcion.Text);
                Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_MENSUAL", tbcosto.Text);
                Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUPO", tbcupo.Text);
                Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DURACION", tbduracion.Text);
                Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIA_CLASE", tbdia.Text);
                Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HORA_CLASE", tbhora.Text);
                

                Comando.Parameters.Add("@msg",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;
                
                string mensaje= Comando.Parameters["@msg"].Value.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(mensaje);
                

                

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar los datos");
                tbdia.Clear();
                tbhora.Clear();
                Conexion.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                Conexion.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debe llenar todos los campos");
        }
```

y este el procedimiento

```
ALTER procedure CREAR_CURSO
@NOMBRE VARCHAR(100),@DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(200),@C_MENSUAL VARCHAR(50),@CUPO VARCHAR(50),
@DURACION VARCHAR(50),@DIA_CLASE VARCHAR(50),@HORA_CLASE VARCHAR(100),@msg varchar(50) output
as
begin try
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    
        if (EXISTS(select * from CURSO WHERE DIA_CLASE=@DIA_CLASE))
        BEGIN
            IF  (EXISTS(select * from CURSO WHERE HORA_CLASE=@HORA_CLASE))
                BEGIN
                 set @msg='Error al guardar los datos'
                 select @msg
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                --PRINT 'NO EXISTE'
                set @msg='Datos Guardados'
                select @msg
                insert CURSO VALUES(@NOMBRE,@DESCRIPCION ,@C_MENSUAL ,@CUPO,@DURACION ,@DIA_CLASE ,@HORA_CLASE)
                END
        END
        
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --PRINT 'NO EXISTE'
            set @msg='Datos Guardados'
            select @msg
            INSERT CURSO VALUES(@NOMBRE,@DESCRIPCION ,@C_MENSUAL ,@CUPO,@DURACION ,@DIA_CLASE ,@HORA_CLASE)
        END
        
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
go

declare @men varchar(50)
EXEC CREAR_CURSO'HTML5','NIVEL AVANZADO','20','22','6 MESES','SABADO','14:00',@msg=@men output
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algunos detalles

- Te esta faltando invocar el `ExecuteNonQuery()`, sino llamas a ese metodo nunca se invoca el procedure
- No se usa el `EXEC`, debes solo poner el nombre del procedure indicando el `CommandType`

Analiza algo como esto

```
var Comando = new SqlCommand("CREAR_CURSO", Conexion);
Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE", CampoCurso.Text);
Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESCRIPCION", CampoDescripcion.Text);
Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_MENSUAL", tbcosto.Text);
Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CUPO", tbcupo.Text);
Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DURACION", tbduracion.Text);
Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIA_CLASE", tbdia.Text);
Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HORA_CLASE", tbhora.Text);

Comando.Parameters.Add("@msg",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;

Comando.ExecuteNonQuery():

string mensaje = Comando.Parameters["@msg"].Value.ToString();

MessageBox.Show(mensaje);
```